# Spring STS editor shows error on aspectj methods, but it compiles and runs perfectly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, roo

I have an odd error after a recent update to the Spring STS platform. The project I am talking about is a Spring roo project. Roo generates ITDs for all roo entities. These generated methods are stored in AspectJ files (.aj).

Earlier my quick fix and autocomplete used to recognize the methods in the .aj files, however after the update, autocomplete does not give the aspect methods and also it keeps showing the red wiggly line.

However the Markers tab shows no error, and the project which is on "Build Automatically" deploys and runs perfectly. I also tried creating an intentional error, and it was immediately caught by the auto build and the error showed up on the markers tab. So I conclude that the project is fine, and the compiler is able to compile fine, no issue with dependencies or such. So it might be an configuration issue which I am unable to locate or sort out. Will appreciate help on this.

Comment: This sounds like an IDE problem rather than a compiler or code problem. My first guess is you're using Eclipse. Have you tried restarting your IDE?